# How to do full text search across multiple tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search

I've been tasked with implementing a search route which accepts a query param and proceeds to search across multiple columns in three different tables.

For example:

- apples
- oranges
- bananas

Should this be composed as three different searches which get munged together or one big search query?

What performance issues should I be aware of or concerned with?

This is a new one for me so any guidance on how to construct this query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into using a [UNION query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html) if you have three separate tables to search against. Query each table, and then "merge" the results of each query together to present a single response if the tables are not the same, and you can create custom indexes on a per table basis to improve the speed of your queries if needed later.